# Rearranging similar terms in an equation

Tags: list-manipulation, symbolic, expression-manipulation, variable, coefficients

In a piece of code I am writing, I run into an equation of the form

`eqn =  Subscript[x, 3] + Subscript[x, 5] + Subscript[r, 0] + 
  2 Subscript[ζ, 3] + Subscript[ζ, 9] == 
 2 Subscript[x, 4] + Subscript[ζ, 6] + Subscript[ζ, 7]`

In more readable $\LaTeX$ format, this looks like

$$x_3 + x_5 + r_0 + 2 \zeta_3 + \zeta_9 = 2 x_4 + \zeta_6 + \zeta_7$$

Given such an equation with `Subscript[x, __]` as the variable of interest, I would like to rewrite it with all $x_i$'s on the left hand side and everything else on the right-hand side, i.e.

$$ x_3 - 2 x_4 + x_5 = -r_0 - 2\zeta_3 + \zeta_6 + \zeta_7 - \zeta_9$$

(I am not interested in the `TeXForm` of course. That is trivial to extract if needed.)

Now given such an equation (`eqn`) I can extract the left and right hand sides as

`lhs = eqn[[1]];
 rhs = eqn[[2]];`

Then the variables on each side are

`vLHS = Variables[lhs];
 vRHS = Variables[rhs];`

But how does one rearrange the equations like so?

**EDIT**: I already have a solution that strips each side of the equation, looks for what involves $x_i$ and what doesn't and reconstructs the equation in this way (by manipulating it as a list). I want to know if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: use Simplify it will arrange the equation and terms

Comment: @Alrubaie, no it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like the following:

```
rearrange[eqn_] := Module[{v, arrays},
    v = Union @ Cases[eqn, Subscript[x, _], Infinity];
    arrays = CoefficientArrays[eqn, v];
    arrays[[2]] . v == -arrays[[1]]
]
```

For your example:

```
rearrange[eqn] //TeXForm
```

> $x_3-2 x_4+x_5=-2 \zeta _3+\zeta _6+\zeta _7-\zeta _9-r_0$

Comment: Perfect, thank you Carl! That works great. In an effort to understand the code, I executed each line outside the module in the interactive notebook. I just have one question: Why does `levelspec` equal to `Infinity` work?

Comment: @leastaction Does the documentation for [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases) help?